# rfkill disables my Wifi and Bluetooth since the Bullseye upgrade. How to disable it permanently?

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

When I boot the Pi, the Wifi symbol is greyed out and when I click on it, it says Wifi is disabled. I enable it and it works fine.

I can unblock everything with rfkill and everything is fine, but this is not a permanent solution.

What I've tried:

- Add `rfkill unblock all` to `/etc/rc.local`, `~/.xinitrc`.
- Make a script `unblock.sh` with the same content and add it to `/etc/init.d`
- Purge rfkill (it is still active afterwards plus I can't unblock anymore

Comment: What Bullseye upgrade?

Comment: Well I changed the apt/sources.list entries to bullseye and upgraded

Comment: Is this an official Pi OS release? Have you asked over in the forums on http://www.raspberrypi.org? If I had to guess, the bugs haven’t been ironed out for the Pi yet.

Comment: Yes, it is, but I haven't asked in the forums yet.

Comment: Edit in the output from `systemctl list-units | grep rfkill`.

Comment: @goldilocks The services are being activated automatically. Disabling them doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: No one said anything about disabling anything.  I asked you to check and see if the rfkill service was loaded -- except I did make a mistake, that should have been `list-units` since `list-unit-files` will always show them whether they've run or not.  I corrected the comment, but probably it would be simpler to just check `systemctl status systemd-rfkill`.  On a healthy buster Pi this should show "Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status".  If not, this is a clue about the cause.

Comment: Yeah, I did check the status. They automatically start again on next boot. I would like to completely remove rfkill, but then wifi doesn't work at all anymore. It says "missing AP", which is weird.

Comment: You need `rfkill` to unblock the interface.  The OS likely *doesn't* need it to block the interface, and/or the hardware certainly doesn't need it to switch or start in a blocked state.  So a quest to "remove rfkill" is essentially a quest to make sure wifi can never be properly enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Bullseye is not yet released, even though the packages have been already pushed to the repo [on 14.08](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=317787). It's expected that not everything will work right away.

Note that you should have used `apt-get dist-upgrade`, not regular `apt-get upgrade` when switching to a new release. There's also an [upgrade script](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=317888) you can use.

Also note that the correct syntax is

```
rfkill unblock all
```

, not

```
unblock rfkill all
```

Comment: The question is not really about Bullseye. ``dist-upgrade`` did not work because of ``The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-8-dev (< 8.4.0-2~) but 8.3.0-6+rpi1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
``

Comment: that upgrade script ... hmm .. if you have 64bit kernel enabled, but 32bit userland - it won't work as far as I can see

Comment: I did a dist-upgrade now. It doesn't solve the issue

Comment: @Bravo You can run a 32-bit userland with a 64-bit kernel, but you can't run a 64-bit userland with a 32-bit kernel.

Comment: @goldilocks - I do know that - I was talking about that upgrade script - it will attempt (and should fail) to change apt sources to point to debian repos for aarch64 - because, running 64bit kernel `uname -m` outputs aarch64 - and the script assumes wrongly that you want 64bit OS - but thanks for the uncorrection

Comment: Fair enough, point taken -- and all apologies.